# Wordpress admin Appearance menu not working

Tags: wordpress

In wordpress admin panel, under Appearance - Menus item was working properly. Suddenly this menu item stopped working. I am getting the below error in admin panel

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in /public_html/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/classes/query-filtering/wpml-query-filter.class.php on line 248

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 277

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 277

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 277
```

Can anyone please help to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be a WPML problem.

Set the max_execution_time to 300 (which is 5 minutes) to see if it works.

You can set it in your .htaccess file with `php_value max_execution_time 300`.

Or you could do it with PHP: `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);`

Answer (score 0):

ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);

Place this at the top of your PHP script and let your script loose!
[this link](https://davidwalsh.name/increase-php-script-execution-time-limit-ini_set)

and set .htaccess file : php_value max_execution_time 300

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried this but not working